# JQuery Mobile pinch & zoom iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a iPhone App with JQuery Mobile and Phonegap. How do I enable the Pinch and Zoom gestures?

I tried it with this:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){
        alert('mobileinit2');
        $.mobile.metaViewportContent = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, user-scalable=yes';

        $.extend($.mobile.zoom, {locked:false,enabled:true});
        alert('/mobileinit');
});
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you want to zoom the whole app or just a div inside it?

if is the second, try with iScroll

[iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
var con=document.getElementById('containerId');

con.addEventListener('gesturechange',function(e){
    if(e.scale>1)
    {
        //zoom in 
    }
    else if(e.scale<1)
    {
        //zoom out 
    }
});
```